# ¿Como cambiar la ruta de una carpeta con mi ruta deseada en C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

mi cometido es cambiar la ruta de raiz(Application.StartupPath) por una ruta en C: ya que se esta obteniendo un paquete de un web service de descarga

```
    private void ProcessFile(Stream package){

        string carpeta = Application.StartupPath + "\\Peticiones Descargadas\\";
        string archivoRuta = carpeta + peticion + ".zip";
        if (!Directory.Exists(carpeta))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(carpeta);
        }

        var fileStream = File.Create(archivoRuta);

        package.CopyTo(fileStream);
        fileStream.Close();
    }
```

Comment: no entiendo, que tiene que ver que estes obteniendo un paquete de un web service con que la ruta debas definirla en el c:\ ? no tiene ningun sentido lo que planteas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podría manejarse directamente con la clase System.IO.Path :

```
private void ProcessFile(Stream package){

    string carpeta = System.IO.Path.Combine("C:\\", "Peticiones Descargadas\\").ToString();
    string archivoRuta = carpeta + peticion + ".zip";
    if (!Directory.Exists(carpeta))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(carpeta);
    }

    var fileStream = File.Create(archivoRuta);

    package.CopyTo(fileStream);
    fileStream.Close();
}
```

Comment: me funciono de maravilla muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder!!